# Conformal Mapping of Simple Non-Convex Polygon onto Unit Circle

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I have seen conformal mappings from convex polygons to the unit circle, and I have seen mappings from the circle to non-convex polygons. I have **not** seen arbitrary simple non-convex polygons mapped to unit circles, which is where my interest lies.

Does such a mapping exist? In either case, what is an example, and what is a specific reference that I can follow up with?

Comment: Isn't this precisely what Riemann mapping theorem says? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem

Comment: Certainly the inverse of such a mapping exists by RMT, so you should be able to compute it somehow

Answer (score 0):

As comments suggest, such a mapping exists by the Riemann Mapping Theorem. A constructive approach to determining the mapping (and its inverse) is given by the Schwarz-Christoffel formula. For reference, the book *Schwarz-Christoffel Mapping* by Driscoll and Trefethen is helpful.